# Python SQL connect to wrong ip adress

Tags: python, mysql, sql, ip-address

I'm trying to connect to my sql server using a simple python script.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="192.168.0.156", user="root",
passwd="Imnottellingyoumypassword", db="mydatabase") # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor() 
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")

for row in cur.fetchall() :
    print row[0]
```

But when I run my script something goes wrong:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 
'root'@'192.168.0.107' (using password: YES)")
```

Why is he trying to connect to my ip address of my laptop instead of the sql server?

Comment: Are you running an SQL server on your laptop? If not then it is connecting to the right server but it's not accepting the login.

Comment: @AsksAnyway - it appears the OP's machine is at .107 and the server is at .156 - the OP wants to know why the program attaches to his machine not the machine specified in the `connect` call.

Comment: The error is access denied not connection failure. Perhaps it is connecting to the right server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is from the MySQL server and not the MySQL driver. What the server is telling you is that connections as root from the IP of your laptop aren't allowed.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the response! It's weird because I gave the root access to any host "%"...